# SqlBuilder returning wrong result

Tags: c#, postgresql, dapper, npgsql, sqlbuilder

I have a query using `Npgsql` and `Postgres`. For building my query I am using Dapper and its SqlBuilder.

When I make the normal statement in the DB it is returning the correct result. When I am doing it via the SqlBuilder it is returning the wrong result.

I tried different way, changed the `addTemplate` or the parameters, but it changed nothing.

Also I have tried to change the line `builder.Where("period = @period", new { model.Period });` in different ways:

```
builder.Where("period = @Period", new { model.Period });
builder.Where("period = period", new { model.Period });
builder.Where("period = @TestPeriod", new { TestPeriod = model.Period });
```

Or is this a more common way:

`builder.Where("period = '" + model.Period + "'");`

```
using (NpgsqlConnection con = Helper.GetNpgsqlConnection())
        {

            var builder = new SqlBuilder();
            var selector = builder.AddTemplate("SELECT * FROM szzRecord.folders /**where**/");

            if (model.Period != null)
                builder.Where("period = @period", new { model.Period });

            var result = con.Query(selector.RawSql);
            return result;
        }
```

The result with the normal sql query for example: `SELECT * FROM szzRecord.folders WHERE period = 24` is returning 251 rows - which is correct.

The result with the dapper query is 1223, which are all rows. So it kinda looks that the parameter doesn't exist. On expecting the `selector` I find my parameter for `period`. I found `Period = 24` in`selector.parameters.templates[0]`. Is this correct? `selector.parameters.parameters` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the `SqlBuilder`'s parameters into your query.  You have:

```
var result = con.Query(selector.RawSql);
```

Change this to:

```
var result = con.Query(selector.RawSql, selector.Parameters);
```